# mac os - How to create and activate conda (a virtual environment) from a bash script?

Tags: android, bash, shell, anaconda, conda

How to create and activate conda (a virtual environment) from a bash script?

I've read a lot of stack overflow posts already None of them really make any sense to me, given that I'm a beginner with bash. Also, most of them pertain to virtualenv, and not conda, which adds to the confusion.

I don't really understand how source or exec works, or if I even need to use it for this purpose.

All I'm trying to do is create a conda virtual environment from inside a bash script, and then activate it. Then run more commands via the bash script on the newly activated "environment".

Instead, what is happening when I run the script below, is that the environment is created, but it's not activated. It's also not helpful that the terminal asks for a prompt to proceed with the creation of the virtual environment (human input required not good).

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirname=$1
conda create -n $1 python=2.7
source activate $1
```

Terminal shows:

```
Jills-MBP:Desktop jillr$ bash site_builder.sh blah
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..........
Package plan for installation in environment /Users/jillr/anaconda/envs/blah:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    openssl:    1.0.2l-0     
    pip:        9.0.1-py27_1 
    python:     2.7.13-0     
    readline:   6.2-2        
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0     
    tk:         8.5.18-0     
    wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0
    zlib:       1.2.8-3      

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was as stupid as calling the entire script with "source" instead of "bash". UHHHHHHHHGGGG!

Instead of

```
bash site_builder.sh blah
```

Use

```
source site_builder.sh blah
```

If someone actually explains why this solves it, that would be fantastical, because I still don't understand what "source" is doing.

[https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do says](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do), *"source is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, in the current shell."*

As opposed to what other shell?

*"source script reads and executes commands from filename in the current shell environment"*

What other shell would they be executed in?

**What shell is "bash site_builder.sh blah" opposed to "source site_builder.sh blah" ??**